# Proof that characteristic polynomial of matrices in certain form is product of characteristic polynomials of sub-matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, characteristic-polynomial

Sorry for the poor title I am really struggling to put the question into words. There is a proof that I am trying to follow but I don't understand the last step. This is the proof:

[image: Proof]

Firstly I don't follow how $p_M(x) = \det(A-xI_n)\det(B-xI_m)$

Furthermore, does this not imply that $p_M(x) = \det((A-xI_n)(B-xI_m))$ but $A$ and $B$ are both square matrices of potentially different sizes in which case $AB$ wouldn't exist?

Comment: To your second question: it does not. Given any two matrices $A,B$, we could consider the product $\det(A)\det(B)$.  **If** $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same size, then we can also say that $\det(A) \det(B) = \det(AB)$.

Comment: About your first question: could you be more specific?  You've included a picture of a nice proof of this fact; is there a particular step of the proof that you didn't understand?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The stage where it says that M is a product of these two matrices, thus we see this... I understand that the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants but I need this last step explained more fully I don't see how the matrix M being a product directly feeds into the last line

Comment: Perhaps you'll find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2026135/81360) helpful, then